# Creating an 'IF' rule in Excel between two cells to create a third cell score

Tags: excel

In order to score a questionnaire which has been input on excel: the first response (which will be between 1-4) is in cell 1 and second response (between 1-4) in cell 2 will determine the score in cell 3.  Thus, to calculate cell 3 on excel I would like to use these two set figures (first and second response) to create a new set figure in a third cell (their score). For example, if E4=3 (first response) and  G4=1 (second response) then I want H4=.25 (that is, H4 will be the blank cell I wish to populate based on what figure is in E4 and G4. There will be multiple combinations based on the participants response in Question 1 and Question 2, hence, I need to apply this rule to all combinations of answers, with each yielding a specific score which I can drag down to each row in column H4.

I do hope this is clear. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It makes sense, but without further details on exactly what combinations will lead to what, we can't help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

If your first response is in `E4` and second response is in `G4`, then place `=VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(E4&G4),$O$5:$P$20,2,0)` in `H4` and drag down as far as you like. This references the table below placed in `O4:P20`. Of course, replace the "Score" values with whatever you like.

```
Response    Score
11          1
12          2
13          3
14          4
21          5
22          6
23          7
24          8
31          9
32          10
33          11
34          12
41          13
42          14
43          15
44          16
```